# Record peak and history of memory usage by a program?

Tags: r, memory

I run a program in R under Ubuntu. I wonder what tool I can use to record the peak and history of memory used by the program?

Are there ways that are or are not specific to R?

The output of `top` changes and flashes away very quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
grep VmPeak /proc/$PID/status
```

Change $PID to the actual process id you're looking for